# How many unordered pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ are there such that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = 126000$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, gcd-and-lcm

> How many unordered pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ are there such that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = 126000$?

**Attempt:**

Let $h= \gcd(A,B)$ so $A=hr$ and $B=hp$, and $$phr=\operatorname{lcm}(A,B)=3^2\cdot 7\cdot 5^3 \cdot 2^4\,.$$ Let $p = 3^a5^b7^c2^d$ and $r = 3^e 5^f 7^g 2^s$. Notice, that given $p$ and $r$, $h$ is determined, so we can count $p$ and $r$. Multiplying $p$ and $r$ we get $$pr = 3^{(a+e)} 5^{(b+f)} 7^{(c+g)} 2^{(d+s)}\,,$$ and so $a+e = 0,1,2$.

For the first case we have $0+1 = 1$ possibility, similarly $2$ and $3$ for the other cases, so the total number is $6$. For $b+f$ we have $b + f = 0,1,2,3$ giving $10$ options. Similarly for $c + g$ we have $3$ choices and for $d + h$ we have $$1+2+3+4+5 = 15$$ choices. Multiplying these together, we get $$15\cdot 3\cdot 6\cdot 10 = 60\cdot 45 = 2700\,,$$ which is not equal to the given answer of $473$.

**Edit:** sorry for the weird variables. I think I've fixed everything, if not, please do point it out

Comment: By HCF do you mean $\operatorname{gcd}$?

Comment: Yea.............

Comment: did you make a typo? Is it a=hr? And similar for b?

Comment: By the way, please edit your post such that all the letters $p$, $q$ etc are inside maths environments (so that they are the same font.). It is very hard to read

Comment: @K.defaoite "highest common factor" (UK) = "greatest common divisor" (US).

Comment: @MNIShaurya  Do not remove the question from the body (i.e., it is not a good form to just put the question in the title).  I put it there because it is one of the *requirements* for a good question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All pair of $m,n$ satisfying $lcm(m,n)=600$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127163/all-pair-of-m-n-satisfying-lcmm-n-600)

Comment: @Sil it does give me a basic process, but dosent answer why my method was wrong

Comment: @MNIShaurya  A problem with your calculation is that you overcounted by a lot.  For example, you know that $a+e=0,1,2$, but the number of possible solutions is just $5$: $$(a,e)=(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(0,2)\,.$$ Note that $(a,e)=(1,1)$ cannot happen (otherwise, this would be absorbed into the gcd $h$). Your counting says the number of solutions $(a,e)$ is $6$.  The same goes for other pairs $(b,f)$, $(c,g)$, and $(d,s)$.  Finally, you counted ***ordered*** pairs, and not ***unordered*** pairs.

Comment: Thank you @Batominovski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have explained why the OP did not get a correct solution.  See my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3760396/how-many-unordered-pairs-of-positive-integers-a-b-are-there-such-that-math/3760416#comment7735420_3760396).  Below is a generalization of the OP's problem.

For positive integers $k$ and $l$, let $f_k(l)$ denote the number of ***ordered*** $k$-tuples $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)\in\mathbb{Z}^k_{>0}$ such that $$\text{lcm}(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)=l\,.$$
Observe that $f_1(l)=1$ always.

Write
$$l=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}\,,$$
where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_r$ are pairwise distinct prime natural numbers and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_r\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Then,
$$n_i=p_1^{\beta_{i,1}}p_2^{\beta_{i,2}}\cdots p_r^{\beta_{i,r}}$$
for some integers $\beta_{i,j}$ such that
$$0\leq \beta_{i,j}\leq \alpha_j$$
for $j=1,2,\ldots,r$.  However, for each $j=1,2,\ldots,r$, at least one $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ must satisfy $\beta_{i,j}=\alpha_j$.  For a fixed $j=1,2,\ldots,r$, the number of ways to make $\beta_{i,j}<\alpha_j$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ is $\alpha_j^k$.  Hence, the number of ways to make $\beta_{i,j}=\alpha_j$ for some $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ is $$\big(\alpha_j+1\big)^{k}-\alpha_j^k\,.$$
This means
$$f_k(l)=\prod_{j=1}^r\,\big((\alpha_j+1)^k-\alpha_j^k\big)\,.$$
In particular,
$$f_2(l)=\prod_{j=1}^r\,(2\alpha_j+1)\,.$$
Now, calculate $f_2(126000)$.

Now, let $\tilde{f_k}(l)$ denote the number of ***unordered*** $k$-tuples  $(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)\in\mathbb{Z}^k_{>0}$ such that $$\text{lcm}(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)=l\,.$$
In the case $k=2$, we have
$$\tilde{f_2}(l)=\dfrac{1+f_2(l)}{2}\,.$$
Why is that so?  What is $\tilde{f_2}(126000)$?

For a general value of $k$, counting unordered $k$-tuples is a tricky combinatorial problem.  I think the easiest way might be using [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).  Using Burnside's Lemma, we have
$$\tilde{f_k}(l)=\sum_{\substack{(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k)\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^k\\ \sum\limits_{\mu=1}^k\,\mu\,t_\mu=k}}\,\left(\frac{f_{\sum\limits_{\mu=1}^k\,t_\mu}(l)}{\prod\limits_{\mu=1}^k\,\big(\mu^{t_\mu}\cdot t_\mu!\big)}\right)\,.$$
For example,
$$\tilde{f_3}(l)=\frac{2+3\,f_2(l)+f_3(l)}{6}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

$126000 = 2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^3\cdot 7^1$

For two numbers to have an LCM of $126000$, either $a$ or $b$ has to have $2^4$ in its prime factorization, and similarly with $3^2, 5^3, $ and $7$.

We need either $a$ and/or $b$ to have $2^4$, so we assign $2^4$ to $a$ first. Then, $b$ can have a factor from $2^0$ to $2^4$, for a total of $5$ total possibilities. We do the same for if $b$ as $2^4$, so $5\cdot 2 = 10$. However, we double-counted the case where both $a$ and $b$ have $2^4$ in it, so we subtract one to get $9$.

Similarly for $3^2$, set $a$ to have $3^2$ in its factorization. There are three choices for $b$, then swap $a$ and $b$ to get $3\cdot 2$, subtract one at the end to get $5$.

Same for $5^3$, we get $7$ and for $7^1$, we get $3$. $9\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 3 = 945$. However, we have a special case of $(126000, 126000)$ because this can be ordered in just one way. Therefore, we add one to $945$ to get $946$, then divide by $2$ because the pairs are unordered.

Hence, the answer is $$\fbox{473}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Think it through:  to find the lowest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ you take the prime factorization of $a$ and $b$.  And find the number whose prime factorization consists of the prime factors of  $a$ and of $b$ and raising them to the higher power they are raised to in $a$ and $b$.  In other words:

If $\{p_i\}$ are the prime factors of $a$ and/or $b$ and $a = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ ($k_i$ may be equal to $0$ if $p_i|b$ but $p_i\not \mid a$) and $b = \prod p_i^{j_i}$ (similarly $j_i$ may be $0$ if $p_i\not \mid b$ but $p_i|a$) then $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = \prod p_i^{\max (k_i,j_i)}$.

so if $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=126000 = 2^4*3^2*5^3*7$ then $a= 2^{k_1}*3^{k_2}5^{k_3}7^{k_4}$ and $b=2^{j_1}*3^{j_2}5^{j_3}7^{j_4}$ where $\max(k_i,j_i) = 4,2,3,1$

So it becomes a combinatorial matter of counting these.

This is easier if we consider ordered pairs.

One of $a$ or $b$ must have $2^4$ divide it.  There is $1$ way that both $a$ and $b$ have $2^4$ divide it.  There are $2$ ways that $2^4$ divides $a$ or $b$ but not the other. And the $2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3$ are four ways that $2$ may divide then others.  So there are $2*4 + 1=9$ we can factor up $2^4$ between $a$ and $b$.

We can do the same for the factors $3^2,5^3, 7^1$ to get $2*2+1=5;2*3+1=7;2*1+1=3$ ways, respectively to distribute those factors.

So there are $9*5*7*3 = 945$ *ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) =126000$.

But we need *unordered* pairs.  So we take the number of pairs where $(a,b)\ne (b,a)$ (ie; $a\ne b$) and divide by $2$.  And we take the pairs where $(a,b)=(b,a)$ (ie; $a=b$) and add those.

But if $a=b$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\operatorname{lcm}(a,a) = 126000$ then $a=b=126000$ and there is only one such pair.

So there are $945-1 = 944$ pairs with $a\ne b$.  So that is $\frac {944}2=472$ *unordered* pairs where $a\ne b$ and one pair where $a=b= 126000$.  So  there are $473$ pairs of unordered $(a,b)$ where $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=126000$.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really follow what's going on in your attempt - it doesn't help that you use some letters with multiple inconsistent meanings and seem to start off with HCF/LCM swapped.

However, writing $A=2^a3^b5^c7^d$ and $B=2^e3^f5^g7^h$ you have $\max(a,e)=4$, etc. This means there are $2\times 5-1=9$ choices for $(a,e)$: choose one to be $4$; the other is one of $5$ options, and subtract $1$ because you just counted $4,4$ twice.

So the number of *ordered* pairs is $9\times7\times 5\times 3$. This is $1$ less than twice the number of unordered pairs, since every pair can be ordered in two ways except for $(126000,126000)$.